# How to write something equivalent to an anonymous class in Java?

Tags: go

This is more of a generic Go question related to interfaces/functions/closures/types/..., but with a concrete use case of performing I/O.

Given an `io.Reader` variable I want to create an `io.ReadCloser` with a custom `Close()` implementation.

```
var file os.File
file = ... // some File which needs to be closed

var reader io.Reader
reader = ... // get Reader from somewhere

var readCloser io.ReadCloser
readCloser = ... // how to create a ReadCloser here?
```

In Java, I would write something like:

```
readCloser = new io.ReadCloser() {
    Read(p []byte) {
        reader.Read(p);
    }

    Close() {
        // my custom close implementation
        file.Close()
    }    
}

// now pass readCloser around as needed
```

How to do that with Go?

Comment: Even though you can create a variable of an anonymous struct, you cannot make that type implement any interfaces, so you'll have to declare a named type. I don't think that's a big loss, tbh.

Comment: Can that named type still be "local" to the current method? Can you please give an example of how to do that, given the local variable `file`? I'm new to Go, so my questions may sound quite Java-ish...

Comment: Type `io.File` does not exist. On the other hand, type [`*os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) already implements `io.ReadCloser`.

Comment: You can't write an anonymous class in Go, because Go doesn't support classes at all.

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question is to find a reasonable piece of code which is equivalent to the given Java code snippet. Again, please excuse my "Java-ish" writing, but translating from Java to Go is actually the heart of this question.

Comment: Translating statement-for-statement, or concept-for-concept between languages which take different approaches, is usually a bad idea. (Between C# and Java it may work, for instance, since they're very similar, conceptually)  A better approach is usually to just re-implement the same high-level functionality, without regard for how the original language accomplished it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking a hint from `http.HandlerFunc` , i could think of the following

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

// ReadData reads data from an io.Reader
func ReadData(r io.Reader) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(r)
    s := buf.String()
    fmt.Printf("read : %s \n", s)
}

// ReaderFunc takes a function and returns io.Reader
type ReaderFunc func([]byte) (int, error)

func (r ReaderFunc) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return r(b)
}

func main() {
    // invoking ReadData with a regular io.Reader
    r := strings.NewReader("data 123")
    ReadData(r)

    // invoking ReadData with an anonymous io.Reader
    r = strings.NewReader("data 456")
    ReadData(ReaderFunc(func(b []byte) (int, error) {
        return r.Read(b)
    }))
}
```

Comment: reason this is already not in the standard library https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24370

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to create your own type that combines a `io.Reader` and 
a `io.Closer` and implements the `io.ReadCloser` interface. Something like this:

```
type ReadCloseCombiner struct {
    io.Reader
    io.Closer
}

func (rcc ReadCloseCombiner) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return rcc.Reader.Read(p)
}

func (rcc ReadCloseCombiner) Close() error {
    return rcc.Closer.Close()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var file *os.File
file = ... // some File which needs to be closed

var reader io.Reader
reader = ... // get Reader from somewhere

var readCloser io.ReadCloser
readCloser = ReadCloseCombiner{reader, file}

// now pass readCloser around as needed
readCloser.Read(...)
readCloser.Close()
```

If you want something more flexible i would concider having a type that take a read and close function instead and then you could pass it anonymous functions (or even `reader.Read`/`file.Close` in your case).